# Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects?

Tags: python, string, concatenation

Our geometry teacher gave us an assignment asking us to create an example of when toy use geometry in real life, so I thought it would be cool to make a program that calculates how many gallons of water will be needed to fill a pool of a certain shape, and with certain dimensions.

Here is the program so far:

```
import easygui
easygui.msgbox("This program will help determine how many gallons will be needed to fill up a pool based off of the dimensions given.")
pool=easygui.buttonbox("What is the shape of the pool?",
              choices=['square/rectangle','circle'])
if pool=='circle':
height=easygui.enterbox("How deep is the pool?")
radius=easygui.enterbox("What is the distance between the edge of the pool and the center of the pool (radius)?")
easygui.msgbox=("You need "+(3.14*(float(radius)**2) * float(height)) + "gallons of water to fill this pool.")
```

i keep getting this error though:

```
easygui.msgbox=("You need "+(3.14*(float(radius)**2) * float(height))

+ "gallons of water to fill this pool.")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

what do i do?

Answer (score 50):

All floats or non string data types must be casted to strings before concatenation

This should work correctly: (notice the `str` cast for multiplication result)

```
easygui.msgbox=("You need "+ str(3.14*(float(radius)**2) * float(height)) + "gallons of water to fill this pool.")
```

straight from the interpreter:

```
>>> radius = 10
>>> height = 10
>>> msg = ("You need "+ str(3.14*(float(radius)**2) * float(height)) + "gallons of water to fill this pool.")
>>> print msg
You need 3140.0gallons of water to fill this pool.
```

Comment: this is the only solution, really? you have to put it into a `str()` function? a bit depressing

Comment: Today one would use an f-string: `"You need {3.14*(float(radius)**2) * float(height)} gallons of water to fill this pool."`.

Answer (score 5):

There is one more solution, You can use string formatting (similar to c language I guess)

This way you can control the precision as well.

```
radius = 24
height = 15

msg = "You need %f gallons of water to fill this pool." % (3.14 * (float(radius) ** 2) * float(height))
print(msg)

msg = "You need %8.2f gallons of water to fill this pool." % (3.14 * (float(radius) ** 2) * float(height))
print(msg)
```

**without precision**

> You need 27129.600000 gallons of water to fill this pool.

**With precision 8.2**

> You need 27129.60 gallons of water to fill this pool.

Answer (score 3):

With Python3.6+, you can use [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to format print statements.

```
radius=24.0
height=15.0
print(f"You need {3.14*height*radius**2:8.2f} gallons of water to fill this pool.")
```