# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to programming a code that successfully converts Fahrenheit to Celsius but I keep getting an error which states "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects"

Code Given Below:

```
a = float(raw_input("What is the temperature in fahrenheit ")) 
b = (a-32)/1.8 
c = "Your temperature is " + b + " degrees celsius."
```

Comment: So, what don't you understand?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948256/cannot-concatenate-str-and-float-objects)

Answer (score 1):

Python does not know what to do when it sees string + float + string (most other languages do not either).

In order to get the result you're looking for, you need to convert b into a string first.
There are a few ways to do this, depending on how many decimal places you want to retain for b once you convert it.

Here's a useful stack overflow question that should help you on your way :)

[Converting a float to a string without rounding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317558/converting-a-float-to-a-string-without-rounding-it)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `b` from float to string:

```
c = "Your temperature is " + str(b) + " degrees celsius."
```

Or, you may use substitution to print your output:

```
c = "Your temperature is %s degrees celsius." % b
```