# How to put together datas into a file?

Tags: python

I would like to collect different type of datas into a file. Here is a part of the code.

```
val = str(float(data[-1]))
val_dB = float(val)
val_dB = math.log(val_dB, 10) * 10
myfile = open('../../../MLI_values/mli_value.txt', 'a')
myfile.write(date_ID + " " + val + val_dB + "\n")
myfile.close()
```

But it gives back an error:

```
myfile.write(date_ID + " " + val + val_dB + "\n")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

How can I solve it to put them together? (into columns) into a file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948256/cannot-concatenate-str-and-float-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
myfile.write(date_ID + " " + val + val_dB + "\n")
```

to:

```
myfile.write(date_ID + " " + val + " " + str(val_dB) + "\n")
```