# Why do I get an unsupported error for +: float and str?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am very new to programming and ran into a problem.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aecas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/Project.py", line 24, in <module>
    finalpay = usercommission + userpay
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'
```

The program that I wrote is:

```
#Prompt user for name
username = input("What is your employee name?")

#Prompt user to enter number of hours worked
userhours = input("Please enter number of hours worked this week: ")


#Prompt user for weekly sales
usersales = input("Enter weekly sales amount:")

commission = float(usersales)

#calculate the commission (.2*user sales input)
usercommission = (20/100) * commission

#hourly rate which I establish
rate = 15

#User pay before commmission
userpay=  (rate * userhours)

#Compute total pay for user
finalpay = usercommission + userpay

print(name, "Your total pay is: ",finalpay)
```

Comment: `input()` returns string values.  Therefore `userhours` is a string, and `userhours * 15` is that string repeated fifteen times.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948256/cannot-concatenate-str-and-float-objects)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `userhours` to an integer. So do `userhours = int(userhours)`.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to understand your problem, it stated "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'", which means your first value is 'float', your second is 'string'

When looking your code, you convert the first input to float, but not the `userhours`. When you multiply a string with a number like: `userpay=  (rate * userhours)`. Your string `userhours` will rurn into duplicate string at `userpay`. Therefore, convert `userhours` first. And then you can add.

Answer (score 0):

`input` is returning a string, not a float. `usersales` gets cast to a `float()`, but `userhours` never gets cast.

Also, in the last line, `name` would be undefined, think it needs to be `username`

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#Prompt user for name
username = input("What is your employee name?")

#Prompt user to enter number of hours worked
userhours = float(input("Please enter number of hours worked this week: "))


#Prompt user for weekly sales
usersales = input("Enter weekly sales amount:")

commission = float(usersales)

#calculate the commission (.2*user sales input)
usercommission = (20/100) * commission

#hourly rate which I establish
rate = 15

#User pay before commmission
userpay=  (rate * userhours)

#Compute total pay for user
finalpay = usercommission + userpay


print(username, "Your total pay is: ",finalpay)
```

Comment: @alfredocastro - Glad I could help. If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer, thanks